# Google MAP Markers

Tags: google-maps

I have been using two different MARKER icons(Red and Green) to show locations on Google MAP.I mean for Club Location I use green MARKER and for Referee Location use red MARKER.It works great but the problem is that when Club and Referee locations are same then green MARKER hide the RED MARKER.so it create confusion to the users that there is no Referee on that location.Is there any way to show both markers even those have same location.Please let me know if my question is not clear.
Thanks Ravi Bhartiya

Answer (score 1):

use a third colour and just have one marker if they are in the same location

Answer (score 0):

before adding markers to map you should group it within some +/- in coordinates, related on current zoom level. And then, when you are ready to add the points, just do whatever you want - move one of them, or use third type of marker...